# Differences between imported Landsat-8 images in Erdas Imagine

Tags: landsat-8, erdas-imagine, digital-image-processing

What is the difference between the images created after importing with USGS Landsat 8 dialog, in particular, the suffixes _msi and _msitir? I understand that they stand for multispectral image and multispectral image with thermal image, but why are there 2 different versions? What uses are there for each one of them that makes it important to have one file with TIR and the other without?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see below, Landsat 8 carries two sensors: OLI (Operational Land Imager) and TIRS (Thermal Infra-Red Scanner). The latter features a resolution of 100m instead of the 30m (15m panchromatic) of OLI. I assume that there are two images because of the difference in resolutions.

[image: Comparison of Landsat 7 and 8 bands with Sentinel-2 (NASA)]

Source: [landsat.gsfc.nasa.gov](https://web.archive.org/web/20180809120925/http:/landsat.gsfc.nasa.gov/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Landsat.v.Sentinel-2.png)

[image: Landsat 8 band designations]

Source: [USGS](https://www.usgs.gov/media/images/landsat-8-band-designations)